# How can I use redux in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/components/partials/userPartial.tsx:101:33
> TS2339: Property 'level' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & { children?: Reac...'.

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/components/partials/userPartial.tsx:102:33
> TS2339: Property 'medal' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & { children?: Reac...'.

But interfaces provided. Component where I getting errors:

```
<NotificationTypes
   level={item.level}
   medal={item.medal}
   referred={item.user}
   points={item.points}
   type={item.type}
/>
Component where intefaces provided

export interface IPoints {
    earned: number,
    total: number
}

export interface INotificationTypesProps {
    level: any,
    medal: any,
    points: IPoints,
    type: number,
}

class NotificationTypes extends React.Component<INotificationTypesProps , any> {
    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
    }


    render(){

        const { type, level, points, medal} = this.props;

        switch(type) {
            case 132:
                return (
                    <span>
                        <Translate value="notification.earned"/> <div
                        className='notify-medal medal-sm-yellow'>{medal}</div>
                    </span>
                );
            case 131:
                return (
                    <span>
                        <Translate value="notification.received"/> {points.earned} <Translate
                        value="notification.pointScored"/>
                        &nbsp;{points.total} <Translate value="notification.points"/>
                    </span>
                );
            default:
                return <div />
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        _CONFIG: state._CONFIG.CDN.static_uri,
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NotificationTypes);
```

Comment: Where is the error exactly? And can you give more context to the code? By the title, it seems that it's a configuration problem of Typescript, but it has nothing to do with configuration. It's a problem of types not matching between what is expected and what is being passed to the component.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.